# xsl:for each select command help

Tags: xslt

`<xsl:for-each select="ComputerStoreProducts/List2/Pc">`

for this code i need it to show the data for Pc,mouse,keyboard but it only shows Pc how can i make it do that as i have to write the code three times and the xsl:sort code doesnt work on all of the prices for each element as it only does Pc the mouse and then keyboard i want them together so the show properly in accending format

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that only `Pc`, `Mouse` and `Keyboard` are children of `List2` (i.e. there are no other children), you could write:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="ComputerStoreProducts/List2/*">
```

If there are other children, and you only want those three:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="ComputerStoreProducts/List2/*[self::Pc | self::Mouse | self::Keyboard]">
```

Comment: Just curious, are those "self::" bits necessary? Is (Pc | Mouse | Keyboard) valid?

Comment: ive tried it and it works but with xsl:sort command doesnt work its put them in order by price